# How to get larger doubles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pi

I am trying to caculate pi to a large amount of decimal places using the Gauss–Legendre algorithm as seen below

[image]

However, it only gives back around 15 digits of pi. Apparently this is because Mathematical operations in Javascript are performed using 64-bit floating point values and 16 digits of precision is right around the limit of what they can represent accurately.

This is my code

```
let a = 1,
    b = 1 / Math.sqrt(2),
    t = 1 / 4,
    p = 1;

let i = 0;
while (a - b < 3) {
    i++;

    let an = (a + b) / 2;
    b = Math.sqrt(a * b);
    t = t - p * (a - an) ** 2;
    p = 2 * p;

    a = an;

    if (i == 100) break;
    let pi = (a + b) ** 2 / (4 * t);
    console.log(pi);
}
```

I was wondering if there was any work around to get javascript to return more digits of pi.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The problem with this method is that also `Math.sqrt(2)` is an approximation. So now you have two problems: a high precision of π and of √2.

Comment: Why use JS? You could use e.g. R or python's `decimal` to get arbitrary precision. If you insist on JS, either implement your own arbitrary precision Math lib or use one of the existing ones. (E.g. decimal.js) but be careful and DYOR as I have seen some calculation errors in some of the Maths JS libraries (in divisions specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interpretation using Decimal.js, with a desired precision of 150 digits of PI...  (Note that "Full page" mode of "Run code snippet" provides a better review of the results.)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/decimal.js/10.4.2/decimal.min.js"></script>

<script>

desiredPiDigits = 150;
Decimal.precision = desiredPiDigits + 5;

let desiredPiPrecision = new Decimal( 1 ).div( 10 ** desiredPiDigits );
let maxIterations = 50;

let a = new Decimal( 1 ),
    b = new Decimal( 1 ).div( Decimal.sqrt( 2 ) ),
    t = new Decimal( 0.25 ),
    p = new Decimal( 1 );

let i = maxIterations;
while ( desiredPiPrecision.lt( a.sub( b ).abs() ) ) {

    let an = a.add( b ).div( 2 );
    b = a.mul( b ).sqrt();
    t = t.sub( p.mul( a.sub( an ).pow( 2 ) ) );
    p = p.mul( 2 );

    a = an;

    let pi = a.add( b ).pow( 2 ).div( t.mul( 4 ) );
    console.log( pi.toString().slice( 0, desiredPiDigits + 1 ) );
    
    if (--i === 0) break;
}

</script>
```